# Python 2D array assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In Matlab I can assign values inside arrays as follows.

```
a = [];
a(end+1, 1:2) = [1,2];
a(end,3:4) = [3,4];
a(end+1, 1:2) = [5,6];
a(end,3:4) = [7,8];
```

and so on. But in Python I can use the append command to append an array to the existing array. e.g.

```
a = []
a.append([1,2,3,4])
a.append([5,6,7,8])
```

My problem is I should assign the first two values at some point and the next two values in some other point as shown in my Matlab code. How can I do that?

Comment: an example of your expected output would be good. the python code you are showing would produce `a=[[1,2,3,4]]`, while it seems from the matlab code that you want `a=[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Comment: I don't think the matlab code does what you think it does. Every time you run the command `a(end+1, ...)` you extend `a` by one more row; you're not assigning the values to the columns.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `extend`:

```
a = []
a.append([1,2])  # [[1,2]]
a[-1].extend([3,4])  # [[1,2,3,4]]
```